# TraceWriter logs not getting to analytics

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I am trying to set up analytics for a test app:

```
public void ProcessQueueMessage(
       [BlobTrigger("blob-injector/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob blob,
       string name,
       [Queue("invoice")] ICollector<string> output,
       [Blob("blob-archive/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob archive,
       TraceWriter log)
    {

        log.Info($"Started processing {name}");
        string content = blob.DownloadText();
        log.Info($"retrieved file {name}{Environment.NewLine}{content}");
        output.Add(content);
        log.Info($"{name} added to queue");
        archive.UploadText(content);
        log.Info($"{name} has been archived");
        blob.DeleteIfExists();
        log.Info($"Completed processing {name}");
    }
```

and I have added an appInsights instance to my azure subscription. I am getting some logging from the App service:

[image]

I have Diagnostic logging set to log to blob storage and I can find my logs there. all info I am finding seems to state that what I have is all I should need. Yet I cannot find my logs in Application Insights.

[edit}
This is a .net 4.6.1 WebJob if that is pertinent.

[update]
I have changed it to use a TelemetryClient and I get logs with that.

Comment: Which version of **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights** are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights 2.2.0`.

I can see the TraceWriter logs getting to analytics as per the steps/code below:

1.Create a .net framework 4.6.1 webjob

2.In visual studio Nuget Package Manager, installs the following version packages:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights 2.2.0

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.5.0

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.1
```

3.In the app.config file, add the following(for local test):

```
AzureWebJobsDashboard, AzureWebJobsStorage, APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
```

The screenshot looks like below:
[image]

4.In your azure web app -> application settings, add `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`, screenshot looks like below:
[image]

5.In the `Main()` method, add the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebJob8
{    
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory())
            {
                var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

                var instrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                config.DashboardConnectionString = "";
                config.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory
                    .AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null)
                    .AddConsole();

            if (config.IsDevelopment)
                {
                    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
                }

                var host = new JobHost(config);
                // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
                host.RunAndBlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

6.The code in the Functions.cs:

```
    public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("1113 this is a queue message: "+message);
            log.Info("1113 it is a test from azure web jobs!!!");
        }
    }
```

7.Publish web job to azure, run it, and then nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> search, you can see the log messages:

[image]

and it also appears in analytics:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a full explanation. I think it is the part in Main linking it all up that I am missing.